# Are there ordinals beyond all the $\omega$'s?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Are there ordinals that are somehow "beyond" all the $\omega$'s?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics) ?

Comment: @Micah and are there ordinals beyond the epsilons or is it just about notation?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *"omegas"*?

Comment: @MartinSleziak the ordinals that are denoted with an expression containing an omega.

Comment: Does "beyond all omegas" mean that such ordinal should be bigger than $\omega_\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$? This would be ordinal bigger than every ordinal. (It seems to be a variation of [Burali-Forti paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox).)

Answer (score 4):

Well. Just off the bat, $\omega_1$ is an ordinal, and it cannot be expressed as a "polynomial" in $\omega$ in any nontrivial way.

Moreover, since for infinite ordinals, $\alpha,\beta$ we have that $|\alpha+\beta|=|\alpha\cdot\beta|=|\alpha^\beta|=\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}$ (where the arithmetic is ***ordinal*** arithmetic, of course), it follows that any finite expression involving countable ordinals is countable. So there is some countable ordinal which cannot be expressed in such nontrivial way.

As luck would have it, we also know that this ordinal is $\varepsilon_0$, and can be defined as the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\omega^\alpha=\alpha$, or as $\sup\{\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\ldots\}$.

---

Of course, if initial ordinals $\omega_\alpha$ are considered in your question as "$\omega$'s" then the answer is negative. Hartogs theorem ensures that if $X$ is a set (e.g. an ordinal), then there is an infinite ordinal which does not inject into $X$, and the least such ordinal is some $\omega_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.